# Browse through image folder with html

Tags: jquery, html, image, directory, gallery

I made an image-gallery with jquery looping through the filenames. Now i want to change the code that I'm able to put images in the folder and they show up in the gallery without having to change filename or code.
Jquery-Code:

```
count = 1;
$("#slideright").click(function() {
    count = count + 1;
    if (count == 10){
        count = 1;
    }
    $("#slide").attr("src","images/gallery" + count + ".jpg");
});
$("#slideleft").click(function() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == 0){
        count = 9;
    }
    $("#slide").attr("src","images/gallery" + count + ".jpg");
});
```

This code works fine. But i want that i don't have to loop through the images. I want that it just takes all images it finds in the folder.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far, and what exactly is not working.

Comment: @bgse I numbered the pictures I have, looped with jquery through them and changed the src of an image tag. But I want to be able to just put pictures in the folder and they show up in the gallery. The problem is, I don't know if it is possible to say "take the next picture in the folder".

Comment: Please update your question with some of your code, e.g. show what you have so far, and where your problem is with your code.

Comment: @bgse updated the question. #slide is the <img>, #slideright and #slideleft are the buttons to switch image.